# How to remove non-functioning Broan 671RB bathroom fan motor?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

Is anyone familiar with this particular bathroom fan? I am trying to replace the motor as it makes a humming noise when turned on but does not spin, but the motor plate seems to be firmly attached to the housing.

[image]

I've watched a few DIY videos and they all suggest that there should be a single tab located opposite the 2 tabs (in blue in the attached photo) which should release the whole plate with a flathead screwdriver, but (after unscrewing the single screw visible) when I attempt to do so, the plate seems to be firmly attached where the star icon on my photo is.

---

Editing to include a better picture.

[image]

With the screwdriver, I can wiggle around all sides of the plate except right where the star/under the model info sticker is - you can see the bit of the plate where I have tried to slide and turn the flathead in my attempts to release the plate from the housing. That corner does not wiggle like the other sections do, and I fear there is a screw behind that requires attic access.

Comment: After you unscrew that Phillips screw at the bottom, can you put a flat-blade screw driver in the slot to the left of the fan and wiggle/pry to get any movement? Also, you might want to move back and left just a bit and get us a pic of the whole of the inside of the housing - there are bits cut off and someone might see something.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan - a better photo included in my original post, as well as some more info to your question.

Comment: Based on the added info, I'd guess there's a screw behind the sticker that requires unscrewing. Have you felt along the sticker looking for any deformation beneath? It looks like the bar code portion is wrinkly as though there may be something there. It's well worth keeping the mfgr/model info on the sticker, but the bar code part could go. Actually, now that you've got a couple of good pics of the sticker, you could scrape the whole thing off, relying on the pics for that info. Write it on the replacement from the pic if the new one doesn't come with its own sticker.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the installation [instructions](https://www.broan-nutone.com/getmedia/5de83f3d-e96a-4f2b-b52c-717e5f9009fc/Installation-Guide-670-671-688-689.pdf?ext=.pdf), they show that the panel with the fan motor tabs into the outer box, and pivots into place.  My guess would be that you need to remove that screw next to the plug, then stick a screwdriver in between the panel and box, adjacent to the screw hole, and pry the box away from the panel.  Hopefully that will release the panel.  You may need to use some kind of hook tool to pull the panel down—or perhaps another screwdriver in the hole in the panel (not in the plug!) where the plug is—to pry the panel down.

Comment: Managed to pop it out - thankfully there wasn't anything in particular (like a screw or another tab) keeping the plate in place in that corner. It was just stuck and needed good old elbow grease. Thank you everyone for your time and help.